# Algorithm to determine back sides of a polygon

Tags: c#

In a 2D scene, given a polygon and a source point, how can I determine the back sides of the polygon, or the sides facing away from the source point?

Edit: In the example picture, the circle represents the sight (or light) source point. The polygon can have any number of sides. I'm looking for example code to identify the sides of the polygon opposite the source point.

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FMqt.png)

Update: I ran across this page that describes what I'd like to do under the "Finding the boundary points" section, but it still doesn't provide example code. [Dynamic 2D Soft Shadows](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/2dsoftshadow/page3.html)

Comment: Your question will be more clear if you add some picture as an explanation. However even if you did this it still be too broad. What have you already tried? Do you have some simple and non-optimal algorithm that we can try to improve? Please [edit] your question and add that details

Comment: It will also help if you updated your question with the answers to these specific questions: 1. Is the polygon always convex or concave? 2. What are the constraints on where the source point can be? 3. "Facing away" and "back side" leave room for interpretation, can you provide a diagram with an example "source point" and "back sides" clearly identified?

Comment: Computational Geometry homework?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I have updated my question with a picture. I admit that Geometry is not my thing. I have also read up on Visible Face Detection and Back-face culling, but they are all tailored to 3D scenes. In essence, I have an "actor" moving about in a top-down, 2D scene, and I want to be able to find the "back-face" sides of the polygons for casting shadows. And yes, I've read up on 2D ray casting and shadow casting, but I have yet to find an example that does exactly what I'm needing.

Comment: Are we given that the source point is strictly outside the poly?

Comment: You ask for "the back sides or the sides facing away", but those are two entirely different things. A concave poly can have a "back side" that "faces" the source point. Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: As for "facing away", we can reduce this to a simpler problem. Suppose we are given three distinct points, A, B and X. If we stand on A and face B, is point X to our right? If the answer is "yes" then segment AB is "facing towards" X. If not, it "facing away". You can answer this question with straightforward vector math; do you see how? Now you can answer the question about poly sides; just pick any vertex as A, and B as the next vertex in counter-clockwise order, and figure out whether X is to the right or not.

Comment: If the simpler subject of shadow casting in Roguelike environments interests you, I've written a tutorial on that here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/shadowcasting/

Comment: I've updated my question with a link that describes what I'd like to do, but I'm still looking for a working code example. @EricLippert, in this example, yes, the source point is outside of the poly. I will also take a look at the link you provided to see if that helps. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very confusing. In your example you have a concave poly, but you link to a page about solving the problem only on convex polys.  You say that you don't know what algorithm to use, but the page you linked to gives the algorithm:

```
For every edge:
  Find normal for edge
  Classify edge as front facing or back facing
  Determine if either edge points are boundary points or not.
```

You say that the step you're stuck on is "classify edges as front facing or back facing", but once you know the normal and the observer point, you know whether the edge is front-facing or back facing!  As the page you linked to says:

> a dot product is performed with this vector and the vector to the light. If this is greater than zero, the edge is front facing.

That is: if the normal is pointing *towards* the observer then it is *facing towards* the observer; that's how we define "facing towards".

This question is confusing and would benefit greatly from you actually writing some code, and then showing us what code you wrote. Obviously you're stuck somewhere, but it is very difficult for us to say where you are stuck or how to unstick you.

My advice is that you start with what you know, which is the algorithm:

```
For every edge:
  Find normal for edge
  Classify edge as front facing or back facing
  Determine if either edge points are boundary points or not.
```

Now, translate that word-for-word into C#:

```
foreach(Edge edge in myPolygon.Edges()) 
{
  var normal = GetNormalOfEdge(edge);
  var classification = Classify(normal, observer);
  var eitherBoundary = IsBoundary(edge.Start) || IsBoundary(edge.End);
}
```

Now start filling out the details: what are the types of those locals? What are the type signatures of those helper methods? Which helper methods can you implement? Which ones are you stuck on?  And so on.

Remember, if you have a concept, make a type to represent it. Don't have a type to represent classifications? Invent one. Now you've got a helpful tool that will enable you to solve harder problems. If you have an operation, make a method to represent it, and again, now you've got a tool that you can build on.  Work slowly and methodically, building up a library of helpful types and methods. Test them independently so you know they are reliable.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. The question is confusing likely because I don't know all the terminology. Maybe I'll pick up a Geometry book and see if I can learn enough to ask more intelligently. :)